# The set of all nilpotent elements is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Given that R is commutative ring with unity, I want show that set of all nilpotent elements is an ideal of R.

I know how to show ideal if set is given but here set is not given to me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The set is given.  It is $\{x\in R \mid x^n=0 \text{ for some } n\}$.  What you need to show is that if $x^n=0$ and $y^m=0$, then $(x+y)^k=0$ for some $k$.  The other properties of that set being an ideal should be straight forward.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I thought quaternions gave a counter example but, well I could be wrong. Something is wrong with me: I keep saying it all wrongly.

Comment: And, I agree with ring of matrices...I do know of examples there...And, it is easy to get an example there without knowing _all_ the nilpotent elements... @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree we [I and the user Matt] concluded this wrongly--We have a CA group here where we discussed and solved exercises--[Sadly, this error has crept in.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3686629#3686629) Thanks for helping me realize. Now, I realize we are wrong. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Kannappan Sampath: Dear Kannappan, One of the key properties of the quaternions is that they are a division algebra.  In particular, as Jyrki notes, they contain no non-zero nilpotent elements.  Thus the set of nilpotents in the quaternions *is* an ideal, the zero ideal.  Regards,

Comment: @Jyrki Please ping me if I make a mistake. I learn from them. The last cyclicc groups incident was rather unfortunate and not intended to offend you. Once again, Apologies on that.

Comment: @MattE Thank you for enlightening me. Looking forward to such helps on this site, when you drop in. Thank you.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: The fourth word in the question (which at this point in time was not edited) is "commutative". So the quaternions are not a counter-example on two counts. BTW, if non-commutative rings had been intended, the word "ideal" would have been ambiguous (left/right/two-sided?).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I brought the idea of dropping the commutativity hypothesis suggesting that Quaterninons gave a counter example. But, I was wrong. Of course, we have that the result holds for commutative rings, no doubt. And, yes, by an Ideal, I have always meant two-sided ones.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The set *is* given: it is
$$\{a \in R\mid a\text{ is nilpotent}\}.$$
Remember that $a\in R$ is nilpotent if and only if there exists $n\gt 0$ such that $a^n=0$.

**Hints.**

1. Is $0$ in the set?
2. If $a$ and $b$ are in the set, can you guarantee that a large enough power of $(a-b)$ is equal to $0$? Think binomial expansion.
3. If $a$ is in the set and $r\in R$, is $ra$ in the set? Here, too, commutativity will be key.

**Added.** For $2$: if $a^k=0$, then $a^r=0$ for all $r\geq k$; if $b^t=0$, then $b^s=0$ for all $s\geq t$. Can you find an $N$ such that each term in the binomial expansion of $(a-b)^N$ will have either $a^r$ with $r\geq k$ or $b^s$ with $s\geq t$?

Comment: how can i show $(a-b)^k=0$?
Other properties are satisfied from hint bt one this one is left

Comment: N=r+s be the largest power then i will get $(a-b)^k=0$
Am i right?

Comment: With $N=r+s$ you will get $(a-b)^N=0$, yes. In fact, $r+s-1$ will suffice, but $r+s$ will do.

Comment: thank u somuch to giving me a such a wonderful guidance and hint to solve my promblem....thanks a lot